# vscode extension: disable specific folder from expanding

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am trying to create a simple vscode extension, the purpose is to prevent selected folder from expanding

Steps:

1. add an new item `Folder Lock/Unlock` in the menu when I right click a folder

```
    "contributes": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "folder-lock.lock",
                "title": "Folder Lock/Unlock"
            }
        ],
        "menus": {
            "commandPalette": [
                {
                    "command": "folder-lock.lock",
                    "when": "false"
                }
            ],
            "explorer/context": [
                {
                    "command": "folder-lock.lock",
                    "when": "explorerResourceIsFolder",
                    "group": "Folder Lock/Unlock",
                    "title": "Folder Lock/Unlock"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

[image]

this works fine when I right click a folder

2. stop that folder from expanding, this is where I stuck

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode'

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "folder-lock" is now active!')

    const disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand(
        'folder-lock.lock',
        (uri: vscode.Uri) => {
            // what should I code here?
        }
    )

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable)
}

export function deactivate() {}
```

I get the folder path from `uri.path`, but how can I change the behavior of the folder using `uri.path`?

or there is a better approach?